# Which current moral philosophers take similar positions to those taken by Anscombe on moral obligation?

Tags: ethics, anscombe

I would like to read current moral philosophers who take similar positions on *moral obligation* as those taken by G. E. M. Anscombe in [Modern Moral Philosophy](https://www.pitt.edu/~mthompso/readings/mmp.pdf).

Her view, as I understand it, is that moral obligation is inadequately grounded without either a divine law and legislator or a philosophy of psychology replacing that divine law and legislator. Furthermore, an adequate philosophy of psychology does not exist and so one should give up on justifying moral obligation and return to an ethics similar to that developed by Aristotle.

Her paper was written in 1958. Since that time I imagine others have continued with similar views, but I don't know who they are. This is mainly a reference request to philosophers working today who take similar views on moral obligation that she took.

---

Reference

Anscombe, G. E. M. (1958). Modern moral philosophy. Philosophy, 33(124), 1-19. https://www.pitt.edu/~mthompso/readings/mmp.pdf

Comment: That objective morality loses its coherence without a law giver was a pretty standard position in the second half of 20th century, Mackie, Hare, Harman, etc., say similar things. Only recently there was a revival of moral realism that tries to challenge it, see [What makes moral realism so popular a standpoint?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/53404/9148)